# Register the same Callback in two different LoginButtons in Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I have two buttons; each one is in a different layout, but they do the same thing because they are each a `LoginButton` from the Facebook SDK.

Can I make the same class handle the same action on two different buttons from different layouts?

I don't like to use an inner class so that's why I've made a new private class called `ButtonFacebook`

```
loginFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new ButtonFacebook ());
```

And the `ButtonFacebook` class is this

```
private class ButtonFacebook implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        /* CODE HERE */

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        /* CODE HERE */
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        /* CODE HERE*/
    }

    private class graphData implements GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            /*CODE HERE*/
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this class to manage two buttons, but I don't think the solution is to make a public class... 
Any advice?

Comment: Please, take a look at [How to ask in StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can do that. Just create a `public class` which implements `FacebookCallback<LoginResult>`:

```
public class LoginListener implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        // Handle onSuccess action
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // Handle onCancel action
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        // Handle errors
    }

}
```

Then set that class as the `callback` in your `LoginButton`:

```
CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
yourLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new LoginListener());
```